# javax.microedition.khronos.opengles. GL10 can not be resolved

Tags: android

What is the solution for "The type javax.microedition.khronos.opengles. GL10 cannot be         resolved" ? I tried to make a small game but i got this error.

Comment: do you have android.jar included  in your project ?

Comment: Now i have added and it is working... I gave solution on the page also..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way i solved my problem.
step1: download the android jar file from  http://ftp.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadandroidjar.htm
step2: right click on your project--properties--add external jar--now give the location of your jar file which you have already downloaded.
That is worked for me. You can try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I made such kind of trick:

1. import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
2. change all GL10 to GL20.

It work's for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to build.gradle's (Module:app) dependencies

**testCompile 'org.khronos:opengl-api:gl1.1-android-2.1_r1'**